# Find Divs with Class x but should not have class y

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul>
<li class="clsLi">
<div class="abc xyz"></div>
<div class="arrow"></div>
<div class="abc xyz"></div>
<div class="abc"></div>
<div class="abc"></div>
<div class="abc xyz"></div>
</ul>
</li>
```

I am trying to select the divs that have the class "abc" but not "xyz"

Comment: In your post, </li> should be before </ul>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
$(".abc:not(.xyz)")
```

You can read up on the not selector [here](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this [:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector

```
$(".abc:not(.xyz)")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.abc').not('.xyz')
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6NSpc/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(this).not('.xyz').hasClass("abc")) {
    //Do stuff with it
}
```

Comment: How is this selecting divs with the class abc?